# Difficulty implementing ComicFlow project

Tags: iphone

Everyone knows there is a free source code application available for iPad named ComicFlow, but the source code is in the google source code - no download project link there.

I copied the entire source code into my new project, but there are some errors:

```
#import "HTTPServer.h"  //missing error
#import "DAVConnection.h"//missing error
#import "cocoahttpserver/Core/Categories/DDData.m"//missing error
#import "cocoahttpserver/Core/Categories/DDNumber.m"// missing error
#import "cocoahttpserver/Core/Categories/DDRange.m"// missing error

@interface HTTPServer (Internal)
- (void) socket:(GCDAsyncSocket*)sock didAcceptNewSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket*)newSocket;//cannot find interface declarationhttpserver
```

I can't find this declaration anywhere on the source code. I know this is a difficult question to answer, but anyone who knows how to deal with this problem, please feel free to answer me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install [hg](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/) (or called mercurial) and type 
`hg clone https://code.google.com/p/comicflow/`. The source repository of ComicFlow has defined that it includes some subrepo such as the cocoahttpserver you mentioned. If you use hg to checkout the source code, they'll be taken care of automatically.

Comment: can u please explain how to do this?Thanks

Comment: I don't have a Mac nearby now, but you can try open a Terminal then type `sudo easy_install pip && sudo pip install mercurial` and type your password if needed. This will setup the forementioned hg tool. Use `hg clone https://code.google.com/p/comicflow/` and you should get the full source code ready.

Comment: Didn't have a Mac to build now, but I saw the cocoahttpserver has been checked out as well, so at least it'll solve your "missing file" problem. :)

Comment: I'll try it this night and let you know the result. :)

Comment: I do what u said yesterday,but the terminal says cocoahttp server didnot find such a directory

Comment: I tried it on my computer. It shows as follow: https://gist.github.com/6408534bb490710f10aa It should build just fine. Would you mind follow my steps again and see if any error spits out?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the owner of the project. What happened at that time is that one of ComicFlow's subrepositories (CocoaHTTPServer) was relocated from Google Code to GitHub and it prevented things to work correctly. I actually fixed this problem a while back.

I also just did some significant changes to ComicFlow and it depends quite less on external repositories so the checkout process should be quite smoother.

1. Install latest Xcode from Apple
2. From Xcode > Preferences > Downloads > Components, install "Command Line Tools"
3. Install [latest Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/).
4. Type this in Terminal `hg clone https://code.google.com/p/comicflow`