# Cooliris kit for ipad ComicFlow application

Tags: ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difficulty implementing ComicFlow project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074523/difficulty-implementing-comicflow-project)

How to get Cooliris tool kit for ComicFlow application in ipad?I tried to create a terminal to get this but it says ComicFlow folder is not empty.what should i do to get the Cooliris toolkit.

```
ast login: Fri Aug 19 10:26:22 on console
admins-Mac-mini:~ admin$ hg clone https://code.google.com/p/comicflow/
warning: code.google.com certificate with fingerprint bf:49:43:68:ed:54:3c:54:fb:19:2f:97:9b:5f:42:e4:3a:79:ae:dd not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
destination directory: comicflow
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 7 changesets with 56 changes to 48 files
updating to branch default
warning: cooliris-toolkit.googlecode.com certificate with fingerprint ed:19:7c:b9:a3:48:27:93:72:74:43:db:26:40:af:e0:7a:90:1c:97 not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
cloning subrepo Cooliris-ToolKit from https://cooliris-toolkit.googlecode.com/hg/
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 17 changesets with 381 changes to 356 files
cloning subrepo Cooliris-ToolKit/DAVServer/cocoahttpserver from https://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/
abort: No such file or directory
admins-Mac-mini:~ admin$
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is the same issue as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074523/ See my answer there for the exact solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install mercurial source code management software and open a terminal. Then enter the command

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/comicflow/
```

When you have ComicFlow source code, open the project and launch the application on your device just as you were in development.

Comment: The command will create for you the folder comicflow. If comicflow folder already exists it will generate the error you get.

Comment: ,yea,i deleted the comicflow folder,but again some errors i got.

Comment: I clone it on my side and it works without errors

Comment: Look at my edit in the question please.i got this error,from terminal.please look

Comment: It seems that you had to install git also to checkout these sources

Comment: how can i install git? Thanks

Comment: Follow git site web instructions http://git-scm.com/

Comment: i have run the comic flow in xcode ,but i cant see any comic book in this app,only some segmented control and a popoover.how to make this a readable app?

Comment: It's a lot out of your question scope. You should ask a new one.